# how to add reference movie into ffmpeg psnr filter in codes (computing psnr)

Tags: filter, ffmpeg

I just want to find out how to use the psnr filter in ffmpeg in codes.

I have followed the codes stated in https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#psnr:

```
sprintf(args, "movie=ref_movie.avi [main];[main][ref] psnr=\"stats_file=stats.log\" [out]");
err = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&psnrCtx,  psnrFilter, "psnr", args, NULL, m_filterGraph);
if ( err < 0 ) {
    avfilter_graph_free(&m_filterGraph);
    m_filterGraph = NULL;
    return false; }
```

But the error message return to me:

`Option 'movie' not found`

I also try this:

```
sprintf(args, "stats_file=stats.log");
err = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&psnrCtx,  psnrFilter, "psnr", args, NULL, m_filterGraph);
if ( err < 0 ) {
   avfilter_graph_free(&m_filterGraph);
   m_filterGraph = NULL;
   return false; }
err = avfilter_link(last_ctx, 0, psnrCtx, 0);
if ( err < 0 ) {
   avfilter_graph_free(&m_filterGraph);
   m_filterGraph = NULL;
   return false;}

...  
err = avfilter_graph_config(m_filterGraph, NULL);
if ( err < 0 ) {
   avfilter_graph_free(&m_filterGraph);
   m_filterGraph = NULL;
   return false;
}
```

but the error message return to me:

```
Input pad "reference" with type video of the filter instance "psnr" of psnr not connected to any source
```

I search psnr filter in codes but there is not much information about it. Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `avfilter_graph_create_filter()` to create a filter-graph instead of the filter. Use `avfilter_graph_parse2()` instead to create whole filter graphs.

Filter graphs are identical to what you'd input in -filter_complex in the ffmpeg commandline. See e.g this example of what string you'd use as input to get a movie element:

```
ffmpeg -filter_complex 'movie=file.mpg[in];movie=ref.mpg[ref];[in][ref]psnr[out]' -map '[out]' -f null -
```

Don't forget to call `avfilter_register_all()` and `av_register_all()` before parsing your filter graph, otherwise the movie element won't be registered yet.

A full piece of example code:

```
#include <assert.h>

#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libavfilter/avfilter.h"
#include "libavfilter/buffersink.h"
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"

int main() {
    AVFilterGraph *filter_graph;
    AVFilterInOut *inputs = NULL, *outputs = NULL;
    AVFilterContext *buffersink_ctx;
    AVFrame *f;

    avfilter_register_all();
    av_register_all();

    filter_graph = avfilter_graph_alloc();
    int ret;

    ret = avfilter_graph_parse2(filter_graph,
                                "movie=file.mpg[in];"
                                "movie=ref.mpg[ref];"
                                "[in][ref]psnr[out];"
                                "[out]buffersink",
                                &inputs, &outputs);
    if (ret < 0) return ret;
    ret = avfilter_graph_config(filter_graph, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) return ret;
    buffersink_ctx = avfilter_graph_get_filter(filter_graph, "Parsed_buffersink_3");
    assert(buffersink_ctx != NULL);
    f = av_frame_alloc();

    for (;;) {
        ret = av_buffersink_get_frame(buffersink_ctx, f);
        if (ret < 0) break;
        av_frame_unref(f);
    }

    av_frame_free(&f);
    avfilter_graph_free(&filter_graph);

    return 0;
}
```

To extract the per-frame PSN values from `f` inside the loop, use something like this:

```
static void parse_psnr(AVFrame *f) {
    AVDictionary *metadata = av_frame_get_metadata(f);
    float psnr[4];

#define parse(a, b) \
    sscanf(av_dict_get(metadata, a, NULL, 0)->value, "%f", &b)

    parse("lavfi.psnr.psnr.y", psnr[0]);
    parse("lavfi.psnr.psnr.u", psnr[1]);
    parse("lavfi.psnr.psnr.v", psnr[2]);
    parse("lavfi.psnr.psnr_avg", psnr[3]);

}
```

To get the final values that are printed to stdout (the sequence-wide PSNR), you can set a log callback using `av_log_set_callback()` and parse the string appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, One more thing I want to ask is about SSIM, what are those parameters can be chosen, just like lavfi.psnr.psnr.y in PSNR

Comment: lavfi.ssim.dB.Y, lavfi.ssim.dB.U, lavfi.ssim.dB.V and lavfi.ssim.dB